# Extracting observations in a loop, and computing means for each iteration

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have two data frames, from which I need to extract variables based on a matching check. Unfortunately just filtering with dplyr does not seem to work as the second data frame is created on a loop from a bigger dataset, iterating through 55 years. For every year I would need the values for A and B, aswell as C and D as identification. The goal is ending up with yearly averages for A and B.

I attempted an if statement inside of the loop, that was supposed to return true if either check passes and subsequently extract the values into a new object. I received the following error: the condition has length > 1.

`if ((df1$C %in% df2$C) | (df1$D %in% df2$D)) { [...] }`

Thanks in advance I am grateful for any pointers as I cannot seem to figure out a way that is not manually computing every step! An overview of the situation is provided below:

df 1) with the relevant variables (A,B) and identity checks (C,D)

| Var A | Var B | Check C | Check D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a2 | b2 | c0 | d0 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 | d0 |

df 2) that observes  identity checks (C, D) in a specific year

| Check C | Check D |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | d1 |
| c2 | d2 |
| c3 | d3 |

Step 1:

I want to extract the variables A and B for each row, dependent on either of the two identity checks matching. Meaning in the example above, a1/b1 would be extracted as both checks match, a3/b3 would be extracted as check D matches, and a2/b2 would not be considered because neither check matches.

The resulting data frame would just include the following

| Var A | Var B | Check C | Check D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 | d0 |

Step 2:

With the final goal, just the yearly averages for every variable looking like this

| Mean A | Mean B |
| --- | --- |
| m1a | m1b |
| m2a | m2b |

Comment: `subset(df, CheckC %in% df2$CheckC | CheckD %in% df2$CheckD)`?? I do not understand the yearly averages. Perharps you should consider using values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without knowing what your data looks like. But, if `df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows AND each row in `df1` corresponds to each row in `df2` (i.e., row 1 in `df1` = row 1 in `df2`), then you could use a loop:

```r
# Initialise df3 and it has the same number of columns as df1
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = ncol(df1)))
colnames(df3) <- colnames(df1)

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  # If the Check Cs match OR the Check Ds match
  if (df1$`Check C`[i] == df2$`Check C`[i] | df1$`Check D`[i] == df2$`Check D`[i]) {
    # If at least one match is TRUE, add row to df3
    df3 <- rbind(df3, df1[i, ])
  }
}
```

Then, if you have a column for year in `df1` and (now) `df3`, you can employ `tidyverse` functions:

```r
library("tidyverse")

df4 <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(year_column) %>% 
  summarise(`Mean A` = mean(`Var A`, na.rm = TRUE), 
            `Mean B` = mean(`Var B`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Alternatively, you could use `tidyverse` functions from the start by first combining the two dataframes. That would look something like:

```r
# Have to change the common column names some how
colnames(df1) <- paste0(colnames(df1), "_1")
colnames(df2) <- paste0(colnames(df2), "_2")

df4 <- cbind(df1, df2) %>% 
  # Keep where at least one matches
  filter(`Check C_1` == `Check C_2` | `Check D_1` == `Check D_2`) %>% 
  # Keep df1 columns
  select(`Var A_1`, `Var B_1`, `Check C_1`, `Check D_1`) %>% 
  # Rename to match original
  rename(`Check C` = `Check C_1`, 
         `Check D` = `Check D_1`)
```

And then you can calculate annual means like above.

Comment: Binding the data frames together worked out, thanks a lot!